# What does "social fabric" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was reading an article and it said:

> The village will pursue the provision of community facilities to enhance the ***social fabric*** of the community.

What does ***social fabric*** in the sentence mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a metaphor for how well the community members interact amongst themselves.  If you consider all the individual members as threads, the "social fabric" is made by having those members interact, thus weaving the threads together.  The tighter the weave (the more frequently and positively the members interact with each other), the stronger the fabric is; the looser the weave, the weaker the fabric, and the more likely to tear (have conflicts that pit one group against another), fray (lose members), develop loose threads (criminals), and otherwise suffer.

*Enhancing the social fabric*, then, means to provide more and better interactions between members of the community so that they can make more friends, be more involved, be happy, be more willing to help someone when there is a need, and be inspired to keep their village a positive, pleasant place to live.

Comment: I agree with the definition of social fabric above, which has to do with interaction, peaceful co- existence and development of the community.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I would describe "social fabric" as social **workings.**

Comment: Social fabric means a country's basic structure, way of life, traditions, customs, and beliefs.

Comment: @sanya: What you said is generally true. But In this context, I take the use of "facilities" to enhance the functioning of society, as opposed to the more static "traditions, customs, and beliefs." Put another way, I endorse the article's basic idea while quibbling with the word choice.

Answer (score 0):

It talks about people from different backgrounds, colors, class and groups who come in a specified geographical location. Social fabric is the ability for them to be knitted together relegating their background, special interest in history for a common goal. This helps enriching culture and gives an opportunity for people to appreciate each other better.